# Bison 3.2 compilation issue

Tags: bison

I am getting the following error while compiling bison 3.2.

```
ar: two different operation options specified
```

Any idea about this?
I am using gcc 6.3.0 to build Bison.

Comment: We need to see the lines before the error to figure out why you get that message.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer , we need to apply the following patch.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bison-patches/2018-10/msg00151.html